# connect Firefox addOn with database

Tags: mysql, node.js, firefox, connection

i would like to create an Firefox add-on, using nodejs, and i would like to connect with database(mysql, mariadb..). I have already see the sdk/simple-storage, but i want to know if is it possible to connect with database.
I 'll try to create connection with my addon and mysql, but when i'trying to run the addon(jpm) there are  errors like  resource://gre/modules/commonjs/crypto.js. 
So my question is,its possible to connect an add_on with database, and how?

thanks in advance

Comment: NodeJS can use MySQL. You need to install `mysql` with the `npm` installer on your `NodeJS` server,

Comment: A local or a remote database?

Comment: @Shadow i ll prefer a remote databese. Is it possible? thank u very much.

Comment: @C0dekid i  made this, but the problem still remaining.. thanks a lot